# Java Apache POI - is it possible to obtain more detailed cell type than returned by getCellType method?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am verifying an Excel spreadsheet. I want to ensure that all of the cells in specific columns, store the same data types.

To do so, I am iterating over rows, and then collecting a set of [CellType](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellType.html)'s returned by getCellType method. Once I have such set, I could ensure that set has only one item and whether it is an expected type.

---

Problem

Unfortunately, Apache POI CellTypes are quite generic. For example NUMERIC is used for whole numbers as well as date types. They also do not provide me an information about size of the field.
Moreover, I noticed that sometimes dates are recognized as String.

My question is:

- should I try create my own enum of more specific cell types and try to parse the cells content as one of those enums (this solution seems to be a significant bottleneck / could slow down my tests),
- OR is there any other method in Apache POI that should I use instead,
- OR should I apply different library to solve my issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have observed is not a drawback of `apache poi` but is how `Excel` stores cell contents. There are only cells of type `String`,  `Numeric`, `Boolean`, `Error` or `Formula` in `Excel`. Whether a numeric cell contains a date is determined only by the cell's number format. If the cell is date formatted, then it shows the number as a date, else not. And if a cell is of type `String` but the string looks like a date, then even `Excel` will not handle that content as a date automatically.

So the only way is determining the different cell contents as shown in [Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features - Getting the cell contents](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents). Mainly differentiate by cell type. For `Numeric` cell type additional differentiate by `DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted`. And for formula cells maybe you additional needs to get the [result type of the formula](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getCachedFormulaResultType--).

Complete example which reads all cells of first sheet of `SAMPLE.xlsx` and determines the cell types as exact as possible.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;

class ReadExcelExample {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook wb  = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("SAMPLE.xlsx"));

  Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

  for (Row row : sheet) {
   for (Cell cell : row) {
    CellReference cellRef = new CellReference(row.getRowNum(), cell.getColumnIndex());
    System.out.print(cellRef.formatAsString() + " ");

    //switch (cell.getCellTypeEnum()) { // until apache poi 3.17
    switch (cell.getCellType()) { // from apache poi 4.0.0
     case STRING:
      System.out.println("is a string cell: " + cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString());
      break;
     case NUMERIC:
      if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
       System.out.println("is a date cell: " + cell.getDateCellValue());
      } else {
       System.out.println("is a numeric cell: " + cell.getNumericCellValue());
      }
      break;
     case BOOLEAN:
      System.out.println("is a boolean cell: " + cell.getBooleanCellValue());
      break;
     case FORMULA:
      System.out.print("is a formula cell: " + cell.getCellFormula());
      //switch (cell.getCachedFormulaResultTypeEnum()) { // until apache poi 3.17
      switch (cell.getCachedFormulaResultType()) { // from apache poi 4.0.0
       case STRING:
        System.out.println(" returning a string: " + cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString());
        break;
       case NUMERIC:
        if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
         System.out.println(" returning a date: " + cell.getDateCellValue());
        } else {
         System.out.println(" returning a number: " + cell.getNumericCellValue());
        }
        break;
       case BOOLEAN:
        System.out.println(" returning an boolean: " + cell.getBooleanCellValue());
        break;
       case ERROR:
       System.out.println(" returning an error: " + cell.getErrorCellValue());
        break;
       default:
        System.out.println("default formula cell"); //should never occur
      }
      break;
     case ERROR:
      System.out.println("is a error cell: " + cell.getErrorCellValue());
      break;
     case BLANK:
      System.out.println("is a blank cell");
      break;
     default:
      System.out.println("default cell"); //should never occur
    }
   }
  }

  wb.close();

 }
}
```